# How can I show all tables in data output tab for plpgsql function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

```
DECLARE
    alltables record;
    table_all varchar;
BEGIN
    for alltables in select distinct table_name , column_name
    from information_schema.colunms
loop
    table_all = alltables.table_name;
    raise notice 'TAB_Name:% , table_all;
end loop;
return table_all;
```

In here, I can see all tables in (`raise notice 'TAB_Name:% , table_all;`) message tab in PgAdmin
but `Data output tab (return table_all;)` return only one column

How can I show all the tables in the data output tab?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, if I understand to your query. You wont to write table function probably.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION xxx
RETURNS TABLE(table_name text, column_name text)
AS $$
BEGIN
  FOR table_name, column_name IN
     SELECT c.table_name, c.column_name
        FROM information_schema.columns
  LOOP
    RETURN NEXT;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

or little bit simply and little bit faster

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION xxx
RETURNS TABLE(table_name text, column_name text)
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY
     SELECT c.table_name, c.column_name
        FROM information_schema.columns
  RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

you can call it

```
SELECT * FROM xxx();
```